# A question about register_activation hook

Tags: plugins, activation

Looking at wp codex it says:

**The register_activation_hook function registers a plugin function to be run when the plugin is activated.**

I am finding this to be not entirely correct, for example i can activate a plugin that adds an extra field to WP registration form (using the add extra field example in codex) which does not require the register_activation_hook function (nor the register_deactivation_hook).

What codex does not tell you is when and when not to use the register_activation_hook, now i am going to guess that the hook is only required when including files for install or creating db tables on plugin activation, i would be grateful if someone who has more knowledge of WP and the correct use of the register/deregister hooks could clarify its correct usage.

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`register_activation_hook()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_activation_hook/) is actually just a wrapper for `add_action('activate_' . $file, $function);` and is only executed when a [plugin is activated](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/the-basics/activation-deactivation-hooks/).

This action/function is meant to be used by anything that should only execute once when the plugin is activated, things which would include stuff like

- adding custom terms to taxonomies
- create new database tables or rows
- running one time db processes which might include updating certain tables, columns or rows
- flush rewrite rules

On the opposite, `register_deactivation_hook()` only executes when a plugin is deactivated. This hook/function/action is meant for running processes to clean up after the plugin, which may include

- restoring db tables, row or columns which was altered
- removing custom db tables which was added by the plugin
- removing any custom options which was added by the plugin that would not be necessary anymore

Comment: Thank you Pieter, a concise answer which has cleared my confusion on the proper use of these hooks.